# Update config file

Tags: c#, configuration-files

I have a problem with update my ConfigFile in VS2013 with C#.
I have this code:

```
Configuration configManager = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
KeyValueConfigurationCollection confCollection = configManager.AppSettings.Settings;

confCollection["ID_Uzivatele"].Value = ID_Uzivatele;

configManager.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(configManager.AppSettings.SectionInformation.Name);
```

(ID_Uzivatele is a String variable)

and configFile

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ID_Uzivatele" value="default"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

My problem is that(error list):
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in KomunikacniAplikace.exe

Anybody has an idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You should rather add a Settings file into your project instead of using appSettings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest looking at an error case where the setting isn't set: this works for me:

(assuming theres a const for the string so you don't get a typo...)

```
const string ID_UZIVATELE = "ID_Uzivatele";
```

Main code:

```
    Configuration configManager = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
    KeyValueConfigurationCollection confCollection = configManager.AppSettings.Settings;

    if (confCollection.AllKeys.Contains(ID_UZIVATELE)) {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Contains key, modifying : was " + confCollection["ID_Uzivatele"].Value);
        confCollection["ID_Uzivatele"].Value = "foo";

    } else {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Doesn't contain key, adding");
        confCollection.Add(ID_UZIVATELE, "Boom");
    }

    configManager.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(configManager.AppSettings.SectionInformation.Name);
```

If the config file is missing, this will generate it( you might want to check that your App.Config is actually being copied to the output folder (which might be the root cause of your error), but building protection against bad config is always helpful.